# AWS Route53: Wildcard in secondary record set (*-Secondary) not working on failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, wildcard, amazon-route53, recordset, failover

I configured a primary and secondary record sets in AWS Route53.
I am using an ALB (Application Load Balancer) for my primary, and a Web hosted S3 static page for my secondary. So both Record Set type is set as CNAME.

The name of the Record Sets:
Primary: `route53.samplesite.net`
Secondary: `route53.samplesite.net`

I was able to redirect my page to the secondary whenever the primary is down.

However I have one problem. My primary is consisted of several applications that works independently. When I say independently, I meant that I do the maintenance to each application separately so they are down at different times.
So, there's domain1, domain2, domain3 and so on set as my primary.
I wanted to set only one Secondary page for all my primary records and was hoping that it could work once I changed the domain name of the secondary to: 
`*.samplesite.net`

and leave the primary to `route53.samplesite.net`,`route53-2.samplesite.net`, etc...

This is the only approached I tried but it is not working.
I know that it will work if I set a different secondary for each primary but is there any easier and a better way to accomplish my goal above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.

On the right hand side, the `*` is not interpreted the same way it is on the left.  It gets no special treatment as a target.

There is no way in Route 53 to map `*.example.com` to reference e.g. `*.example.org` so that for any value, the answer contains the same prefix with a different suffix.  You'll need to configure them individually.

Comment: I thought it was possible..I misunderstood the information stated in here regarding the use of * in naming record sets. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html. Thank you for your input!